# React-Redux increasing and decreasing item quantity in Home page and Cart page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, e-commerce, react-state-management

I am looking for a solution to parallelly update the quantity in homepage as well as cart page. For now, I can increase/decrease the quantity of the items in the cart after adding it, but in the homepage after clicking the add button, the +/- button should appear and I should increase/decrease the items in the homepage and check in the cart page with the same updated quantity.

Here is the link to the shopping cart page which iam trying to achieve http://doodlebluelive.com:2332/wellness

(AddtoCart and increase/decrease functionality) ItemList.js

```
const url = 'http://doodlebluelive.com:2319/api/v1/product?page=1&size=20';
    const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = (currentPage) => {
        axios.get(`http://doodlebluelive.com:2319/api/v1/product?page=${currentPage}&size=20`).then(res => {
            setDataList(res.data.data.list);
        })
    }

 useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then(res => {
            setDataList(res.data.data.list);
            console.log(res.data.data.list)
        })
    }, [])

    const cart = useSelector((state) => state)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const isCart = (id) => {
        let data = cart.find(item => id === item._id);
        if (data) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

return(
{dataList.map(item => {
                    item.quantity = 1;
                    return (
                    <div className="adding-button">
                                    {isCart(item._id) ?
                                        <div className="cart" key={item._id}>
                                            <div class="adding-qty">
                                                <button
                                                    onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "INCREASE", payload: item })}
                                                >
                                                    <span className="plus-qty">+</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="qty-info">
                                                <p>
                                                    {item.quantity}
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="decrease-qty">
                                                <button
                                                    onClick={() => {
                                                        if (item.quantity > 1) {
                                                            dispatch({ type: "DECREASE", payload: item });
                                                        } else {
                                                            dispatch({ type: "REMOVE", payload: item });
                                                        }
                                                    }}
                                                >
                                                    <span className="minus-qty">-</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        : <button onClick=
                                            {() => dispatch({ type: "ADD", payload: item })}>
                                            Add To Cart
                                        </button>}
                                </div>
  )
                }
                )
                }
```

(Listing Cart items) Cart.js

```
const cart = useSelector((state) => state);
    console.log(cart);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

return(
{cart.map((item) => {
                                    return (
 <div className="item-quantity">
                                                    <button
                                                        onClick={() => {
                                                            if (item.quantity > 1) {
                                                                dispatch({ type: "DECREASE", payload: item });
                                                            } else {
                                                                dispatch({ type: "REMOVE", payload: item });
                                                            }
                                                        }}
                                                    >
                                                        <span className="minus-qty">-</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <div className="qty-number">
                                                        <p>{item.quantity}</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <button
                                                        onClick={() => {
                                                            dispatch({ type: "INCREASE", payload: item });

                                                        }
                                                        }
                                                    >
                                                        <span className="plus-qty">+</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
    );
                                })}
)
```

Reducers.js

```
const initialState = {
    cart: [],
}

const Reducer = (state = initialState.cart, action) => {
    if (action.type === "ADD") {
        let tempcart = state.filter((item) => item._id === action.payload._id);
        if (tempcart.length == 0) {
            return [...state, action.payload];
        }
        else {
            return state;
        }

    }
    if (action.type === "REMOVE") {
        return state.filter((item) => item._id !== action.payload._id);
    }
    if (action.type === "INCREASE") {
        let tempcart = state.map((item) => {
            if (item._id === action.payload._id) {
                return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 };
            }
            return item;
        });
        return tempcart;
    }
    if (action.type === "DECREASE") {
        let tempcart = state.map((item) => {
            if (item._id === action.payload._id) {
                return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity - 1 };
            }
            return item;
        });
        return tempcart;
    }

    if (action.type === "INC") {
        let tempcart = state.filter((item) => {
            if (item._id === action.payload._id) {
                return { ...item, count: item.count + 1 };
            }
            return item;
        });
        return tempcart;
    }

    return state;

};
export default Reducer;
```

I have added the same functionality ("INCREASE" and "DECREASE" for the both the components(not sure if correct) and the quantity updation is working fine in cart page but not in home page. Please help me with this !!

Comment: Just noticed the following lines in homepage

 - 
return(
{dataList.map(item => {
                    item.quantity = 1; - 

item.quantity = 1; would set the quantity to 1 on the screen everytime the state changes

Comment: @adhinarayan Yes i have given it as initial value, but even if i remove it it doesnt work